# If string ends and starts with "*" in Python

Tags: python

Is there a simple if statement to battle this problem? The first block is my code so far, the second block is the boolean output I wish would be printed.

```
if string.startswith("*") and string.endswith("*"):
    return True
else:
    return False



print(string_startend_function('*JohnDoe*'))  # True (This answer my code can achieve)
print(string_startend_function('*'))  # False (This answer my code can't achieve)
```

I need my code to display False if the startswith * and endswith * are the same singular *, is there anyway to achieve this, with adding a elif statement after the if statement?

Comment: add something like `and len(string) > 1` to your if

Comment: Thank you! this solved it. Wish I could choose this as the best asnwer, don't see an option so far sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Since `'*'` is the only possible value for `string` where `string.startswith("*") and string.endswith("*")` is `True` and where the function should return `False`, you can simply add an inequality test to make sure that `string` is literally not `'*'`:

```
return string != '*' and string.startswith("*") and string.endswith("*")
```

Comment: Thank you, should've come to this conclusion myself haha!

Comment: Probably the worst case of premature optimization, but I would prefer `return string != '*' and string.startswith('*') and string.endswith('*')`. Saves 2 useless checks in an obvious case

Comment: @DeepSpace Totally agreed. I rushed into the answer indeed.

Comment: @DeepSpace: But it's the test least likely to pass (presumably); you want the most likely to fail tests first, so on average on you only perform one test. Sure, `!= '*'` is the cheapest test, but it's going to short-circuit only a trivial percentage of the time, so it increases the average number of tests. I suspect it's actually a cases of pessimization in most cases, not optimization at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Totally agreed too (presumably you mean it's the test least likely not to pass).

Comment: @blhsing: Oops, yeah, that was supposed to begin "But it's the test least likely to fail (presumably)..."

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a regular expression like `^\*.*\*$`, meaning "start, literal `*`, more stuff, literal `*`, end"

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"^\*.*\*$", "*") is not None
False
>>> re.match(r"^\*.*\*$", "*JohnDoe*") is not None
True
>>> re.match(r"^\*.*\*$", "*invalid") is not None
False
```

Comment: `match` matches from the start of the string so no need for `^` :)

Comment: @Tomerikoo That's right, but somehow I prefer symmetric `^` and `$`, and while I could do that with `search` too, `match` is more explicit in what its doing here.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which comes to me is regular expression, BUT:

For short code, how about this code?

```py
return len(s) > 1 and s[0] + s[-1] == "**"
```

with not using `startWith` or `endWith` method :)